# Confusion regarding action in the form

Tags: laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and I am trying CRUD operations using `Resource Controller`. The problem I am facing is regarding what should be the `action` in create a task form. Let me give you an overview, how the application is designed. I have created separate directories for MVC as listed below:

- Todo_Model\todo_model.php
- Todo_Controller\todo_controller.php
- Todo_View\home.blade.php
- Todo_View\create.blade.php

Route: Route::resource('todo','Todo_Controller\todo_controller');

route:list
[image]

Controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        return view('Todo_View\home');
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('Todo_View\create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $todo= new todo_model();
        $todo->title=$request->title;
        $todo->body=$request->body;
        $todo->save();
        return redirect('todo');

    }
```

create.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="../todo">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="body" value="" placeholder="Body"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
 </form>
```

Now the problem is that the `action` of the form should be `todo` as can be seen in the `route:list` but when I hit submit with that I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` and the URL shown is `http://localhost/laravel-7/blog/public/todo/todo`. But during the hit and trial I figured out I should use  form action as `../todo`. I am highly confused as to why do I have to use that action as it doesn't make any sense because in the route list, URI is clearly mentioned as `todo`

Another point, when I hit index page, URI is `http://localhost/laravel-7/blog/public/todo` and when I get redirected from home page to create page, the URI is `http://localhost/laravel-7/blog/public/todo/create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `action` with native php in laravel.

Replace your  `action="../todo"` with `action="{{url('todo')}}"`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('todo')}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="body" value="" placeholder="Body"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But, I am sure that I can simply use `todo` if I am not using a resource controller as I have used the same in another project and it worked fine there. Why is it creating a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the route exactly no need for saying where the file is actually located so `action="/todo"` would work fine

Comment: It does not work for me. I have tried it out and as specified, I am getting an exception.